# JavaScript error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input) Why?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angular

Why? I've checked and for me there is no missing a ) neither }.

**The class:**

```
export class Boletim {
    nuMes: string =  '';
    nuAno: string =  '';
    dsTitulo: string =  '';
    dsDetalhes: string = '';
    urlImagem: string = '';
    urlPdf: string = '';
}
```

**My component:**

```
export class HomeBoletimComponent {

    item: Boletim[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.fnListar();
    }

    fnListar() {
        this.dbService.get('Boletim/ListaBoletim').subscribe(result => {
            this.item = result;
        });
    }

    constructor(
        private dbService: DbService,
        private SpinnerService: SpinnerService
    ) { }
}
```

**The service and the class service:**

```
[Route("ListaBoletim")]
[HttpGet]
public List<Boletim> ListaBoletim()
{
    try
    {
        var listaBoletim = bBoletim.ListAll();

        if (listaBoletim.Count > 0)
        {
            return listaBoletim;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
}

public partial class Boletim
{
    public int IdBoletim { get; set; }
    public short NuMes { get; set; }
    public short NuAno { get; set; }
    public string DsTitulo { get; set; }
    public string DsDetalhes { get; set; }
    public string UrlImagem { get; set; }
    public string UrlPdf { get; set; }
}
```

I noticed that the type of the properties nuMes and nuAno are different between the service and the class, this could be the problem?

Comment: Provided what you have there is inside a class definition or object initializer, it's fine in any modern environment (it's ES2015+ method syntax). If it's in an object initializer you're running in an obsolete or older environment like IE8-IE11, you'd need to use `fnListar: function() ...` If it's just on its own, a standalone function, then it's missing the `function` keyword at the beginning. So we'll need more context before we can help you.

Comment: Maybe you missed a `:` and `=>` in `fnListar: () => {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
export class HomeBoletimComponent {

  item: Boletim[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fnListar();
  }

  fnListar() {
    this.dbService.get('Boletim/ListaBoletim').subscribe(result => {
      this.item = result;
    });
  }

  constructor(
    dbService: DbService,
    spinnerService: SpinnerService
  ) {
    this.dbService = dbService;
    this.spinnerService = spinnerService;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried but a I got the error: Property 'dbService' does not exist on type 'HomeBoletimComponent'. and Property 'SpinnerService' does not exist on type 'HomeBoletimComponent'.

Comment: Define `dbService` and `spinnerService` as component variables after `item` and get them correct type. @LeonardoLima

Comment: Does it work?? Your main code has `private SpinnerService: SpinnerService` which is a variable name equal to Component name. I correct that in my code. Consider it too. @LeonardoLima

Answer (score -1):

I agree with [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder):

> Provided what you have there is inside a class definition or object initializer, it's fine in any modern environment (it's ES2015+ method syntax). On its own, it's missing the function keyword at the beginning.

But further, I would like to mention that you might be getting error because it's expecting parentheses as you're not using return statement inside the curly brace:

```
 this.dbService.get('Boletim/ListaBoletim').subscribe(result => 
   ({this.item = result})
 )
```

Or, you may also have written using `return` statement:

```
 this.dbService.get('Boletim/ListaBoletim').subscribe(result => 
   return {this.item = result} // To fix, use parentheses
 )
```

BTW, I'm not totally sure if the error is thrown by not using parentheses. Because, it depends on the project environment. I mean how you setup or working on babel project,...? If this is relevant to that, then using parentheses like above will solve the issue.

I've written this answer because such fixes worked very smoothly while working on react app created by create-react-app. Hope, this helps to you as well.